# how to separate installed packages based on their installation type?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Consider a case that I have few list of packages installed in my Ubuntu. Among them few are installed from apt-get,aptitude & few from source tars.

How can I group them separately  based on their installation process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The ones that were installed using APT/DPKG or any package manager can be listed easily. The installed from sources, tarballs, summary *anything installed manually* without a package maintainer is more tricky. You would need a list of all possible files and the software that installed it and such list is either too big and possibly unmaintained. So the answer is no, there's no way to list the package that were installed manually from sources unless they use some sort of package manager.